# Why does apt say an enormous 16.7 GB additional disk space is needed?

Tags: 14.04, apt, upgrade, updates

On Ubuntu 14.04 LTS running in a Proxmox 4.4 container:

```
$ apt update
$ apt dist-upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages will be upgraded:

  bind9 bind9-host bind9utils libbind9-90 libdns100 libisc95 libisccc90
  libisccfg90 liblwres90 linux-libc-dev webmin-virtual-server

11 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 4.500 kB of archives.

After this operation, **16,7 GB of additional disk space** will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] n
Abort.
```

How is it possible?
I try on several Proxmox Container 14.04: same 16.7 GB!

I never see an error in the disk space need.
It's bigger than the Proxmox container (6 GB). I haven't yet done this dist-upgrade.

Comment: This can't be right, as it will download only 4.5Mb. The space needed for the unzipped files can be several times larger than the downloaded data, but not 3500 times larger. It must be a bug ( and a fun one to report as well).

Answer (score 1):

I got the same message on 14.04 (not sure which container) though I tried to apt-get upgrade, not dist-upgrade.
It showed me exactly the same 16.7 GB. Anyway I proceeded with the upgrade and everything went well. Only some 30 MB of additional space were used instead of 16.7 GB. So it's definitely a bug.

EDIT: A month has passed and here's what I got today on 16.04.2

```
apt-get uprgade
...
2 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 3,008 kB of archives.
After this operation, 16.7 GB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n]
```

The same 16.7 GB but now it will be freed.

Comment: Same problem with 22.04. apt claimed 353 GB additional disk space is needed but only 575 MB is downloaded. After apt upgrade I still had the same 22 GB free as before.